# Issue with the while statement closing my console

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BehindClosedDoors
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userValue;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, Welcome to Behind Closed Doors");
            Console.WriteLine("A fun and exciting  game");
            Console.WriteLine("Roll Two dice and the add the value's together and enter that number");
            userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            do while (userValue == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Kiss");
                Console.WriteLine("Now roll another number");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while ((userValue = Console.ReadLine()) == "3");
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Give");
                Console.WriteLine("Now roll another number");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while ((userValue = Console.ReadLine()) == "4")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Foot Rub");
                Console.WriteLine("Now roll another number");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while (userValue == "2" + "3" + "4")
            {
                //
            }
           // else if (userValue == "5")
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make it so when I run this code I can input 2 3 or 4 as many times as I want and get that text without the console closing on me. As it stands now I can chose two and then on the third close's the console.

Comment: You are aware that in the first while loop, you just read the console but never assign it?

Comment: I'd suggest reading about the while loop to understand how it works and how to use it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Comment: Looks Like I need to go back and re read some come examples of what I am trying to do with the loops. I only about two week in learning C#

Answer (score 3):

I think you need single loop with switch:

```
do
{
   userValue = Console.ReadLine();

    switch(userValue)
    {
        case "2": //..
        case "3": //..
        case "4": //..               
    }

}while (userValue == "2" || userValue == "3" || userValue == "4")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while is checking for "2"+"3"+"4" ie "234" as a string.

You probably want something like

```
userValue == "2" || userValue == "3" || userValue == "4"
```

Comment: Ok this keep the Console from closing I can hit any number I want as many times as I want and it stays open. My new issue is not matter if I type 2 3 or 4 I get the text Kiss. I can even enter 23 and get that text.

Comment: In the "while" loop for 2 - you never reassign userValue. So it's always 2.

Comment: Also do you really want the loop like that? Is there any reason you're not using ifs or a switch statement (like Sergey suggested?)

Comment: Yes I am have been teaching myself C# and trying to understand it by trying to complete small project's I think up I will read up on the switch statement